# Как добавить запись в базу данных Django через форму имея конкретные переменные и 1 инпут?

Tags: django, forms

```html
class Messages(models.Model):
    req_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=4096, blank=True, null=True)
    user_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    agent_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.req_id, self.message, self.user_status, self.date)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'messages'
```

```html
class Requests(models.Model):
    req_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    inn = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    req_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.req_id, self.user_id, self.inn, self.req_status)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'requests'
```

```py
def requests(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        form.save()

    form = MessageForm()
    messages = Messages.objects.all().order_by("req_id")
    tasks = Requests.objects.all().order_by("req_id")
    context = {"title": "Запросы", "tasks": tasks, "messages": messages, "form": form}
    return render(request, "main/requests.html", context)
```

```py
class MessageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Messages
        fields = ['req_id', 'message', 'user_status', 'date']
```

хочу реализовать добавление записи в базу данных через форму, есть 4 поля в бд, req_id, message, user_status, date, мне надо сделать так чтоб в форме был инпут с добавлением message, а остальные данные заносились без инпутов.

```html
{% block content %}{% for el in tasks %}
<div class="list-group w-auto">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3" aria-current="true">
        {% if el.req_status == "confirm" %}
        <span width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0">✅</span>
        {% elif el.req_status == "answered" %}
        <span width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0">⏳</span>
        {% else %}
        <span width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0">❌</span>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <h6 class="mb-0">{{ el.user_id }}</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">{{ el.inn }}</p>
            </div>
            <small class="opacity-50 text-nowrap">{{ el.req_id }}</small>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% for re in messages %}
{% if re.req_id|stringformat:"s" == el.req_id|stringformat:"s" %}
<div class="chat_section">
    <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">{{re.message}}</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.message }}
    {% form.req_id %}: {{re.req_id}} -ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ НЕ ПОНИМАЮ КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО ПРИСВОИТЬ, И МОЖНО ЛИ ВООБЩЕ()
    {% form.user_status %}:{{re.user_status}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Отправить</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: все что не через ипуты реализуйте во view. Зачем туда-сюда лишние данные передавать. Если у вас есть пользователь, то работайте с `request` сущностью, если вы работаете с датой, то в самой `view` и используйте это значение и тд

Comment: А можешь подсказать как во view реализовать то,что я хочу. Мне по кнопке надо заносить текст и конкретные поля именно того элемента массива в котором инпут

Comment: в сам вопрос добавьте вашу вьюшку, которая работает с этим темплэйтом, подправлю. Для этог вы можете нажать [edit] под самим вопросом

Comment: @Dmitry посмотри, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сразу убирайте из формы все кроме одного поля, которое будете вводить. Оставляйте один инпут

в самой вьюшке

```py
def requests(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        message_from_template = form.cleaned_data['message']
        user_status = request.user.status
        message = Message(message=message_from_template, user_status=user_status)
        message.save()

    form = MessageForm()
    messages = Messages.objects.all().order_by("req_id")
    tasks = Requests.objects.all().order_by("req_id")
    context = {"title": "Запросы", "tasks": tasks, "messages": messages, "form": form}
    return render(request, "main/requests.html", context)
```

Написал более понятно вам, создается сущность класса `Message()` и в нее добавляется запись. Почему пропущены `req_id` и `date`? Эти данные должны быть определены в самой модели. Я это вижу так

```py
class Message(models.Model):
    req_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # остальные поля
```

Документация по автоматическому добавлению даты [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add).

По сути у вас получится, что из темплейта приходит только одно - это сообщение. Все остальное может обрабатываться бекэндом без дополнительных действий

Comment: 'User' object has no attribute 'status'

Comment: Все работает, но мне надо заполнять поле req_id, т.к есть модель request и там он primary key.

Comment: @АртёмМиняев не очень понятно, подправил ответ как понял

Comment: Почему он пишет, что у request нет атрибута req_id

Comment: @АртёмМиняев значит его там нет, у вас две связаные таблицы что ли?

Comment: @АртёмМиняев добавляйте модели в вопрос, так просто гадание. Или сами разберетесь?

Comment: @user:209304 Добавил модели, я их импортировал с postgresql

Comment: @АртёмМиняев явно нарушение в логике, передумайте, свяжите таблицы по полям. Если у вас есть общее поле для двух таблиц, то очевидно нужно использовать отношения "один ко многим" или "многие ко многим". Вы исользуете одно значение для двух таблиц. Второе, не используйте в именах ваших классов имена функций и библиотек. `requests` - это библиотека для запросов. Третье, возьмите ручку и бумагу, нарисуйте отношения между полями в различных таблицах. По логике, которую я понял (может это и не так), то проще переписать, чем мучаться дальше. Это нормально, так бывает

Comment: на первый вопрос я вам дал ответ, все дальнейшие рассуждения - это уже другие вопросы. Если у вас возникают новые вопросы по ходу дела, то вопрос, который получил ответ можете закрывать и писать новый вопрос. Здесь такая политика: один конкретный вопрос -> конкретные ответы с вариациями.